# Is Wix Custom Action project can be signed?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, .net-4.6, wix3.10

We are using Wix for installation project and having one separate CustomAction Project in that.
CustomAction project (strongly signed) has one dependent project (called it ProjA) reference which is strongly signed.

**Case1#** Both Custom Action and ProjA projects are signed then getting following error.
Could not load file or assembly XXX.CustomAction, Version=2.5.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXX' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A).

**Case2#** If we removed strongly signed from Custom Action Project and keep ProjA signed then we are getting following error
Could not load file or assembly XXX.ProjA, Version=2.5.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXX' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A).

**Case3#** If we removed strongly signed from both Custom Action and ProjA projects the setup running successful.
So we are looking for case#1 to be resolved.

Does anybody have an idea on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading this background on how DTF works:

http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2008/05/deployment-tools-foundation-dtf-custom.html

When you rename your wrapped CA DLL  to .zip and look at it's contents you are likely not going to see your signed DLLs in there.

It's been awhile since I did this but I think it has to do with SfxCA's default build behavior with regard to trying to decide what it should and shouldn't pack.  (Say you DLL yes,  some other DLL yes, system.dll no )  and I think it takes code signing into consideration.   Toggle the CopyLocal (true|false) flag on your reference and rebuild / reexamine using the zip technique.